# Basically I want to replace the unwanted repeated characters words with their correctly spelled words

Tags: java

I want to take a text file as input , read the words , check each word with the englishwordslist , if the words are misspelled (like unwanted repeated characters)then replace the word with the correct word in the same file.

if the word is beautifullllll then my code works fine..it writes beautiful into the file but if the word is beautttifulll then my code will not work properly.First i'm removing all the repeated characters in the word cross-checking with the wordslist if not present then allowing only one successive repetition of character.Since beautttifulll has more than one character repeated the output i get is beauttifull but its not in the dictionary.

Please help me with this.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ownspell {
public static String result(String input, boolean doubleLetter){
    String pattern = null;
    if(doubleLetter) pattern = "(.)(?=\\1{2})";
    else pattern = "(.)(?=\\1)";
return input.replaceAll(pattern, "");
}
public static int checkingdic(String word) throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
{
      FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream("G:/englishwordslist.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String sample=" ";
      word.toLowerCase();
      int flag=1;
      while((sample=br.readLine())!=null && flag==1)
       {
          if(sample.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
           { 
               flag=0;
           }
       }
      fstream.close();
      return flag;
}
public static void addtofile(String old,String newv) throws IOException , FileNotFoundException
{

    File file = new File("G:/1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String sample = "", oldtext = "";
    while((sample = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        oldtext += sample + "\r\n";
    }
    reader.close();
    // replace a word in a file
    String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(old, newv);



    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("G:/1.txt");
    writer.write(newtext);writer.close();

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , FileNotFoundException
{
    try{

        FileInputStream f1stream=new FileInputStream("G:/1.txt");
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(f1stream);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(in1));
        String sample1=" ";
        while((sample1=br1.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String a[]=sample1.split(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                int flag;
            if(a[i].length()>0)
            {
                flag=checkingdic(a[i].toLowerCase());
                if(flag==0)
               {
                   System.out.println(a[i]+" :Word is found");
               }
               else
               {
                  // System.out.println(a[i]+" :Word is not found");
                   String output=result(a[i],false);
                   flag=checkingdic(output.toLowerCase());
                   if(flag==1)
                   {
                      output=result(a[i],true);
                      flag=checkingdic(output.toLowerCase());
                      if(flag==0)
                      {
                           addtofile(a[i],output);
                           System.out.println(a[i]+" :Word is found");
                      }
                      else
                      {   
                         System.out.println(a[i]+" :Word is not found");
                      }
                   }      
                   else
                   {
                      addtofile(a[i],output);
                      System.out.println(a[i]+" :Word is found");
                   }
                   }
               }            
            }
            }

      f1stream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }


}
}
```

Ex :

1.txt : This boook is beautttifullll

Desired Output : This book is beautiful

Output this code gives : This book is beautttifullll

It doesnot correct the word beautttifullll because the function result gives beauttifull as output since it is not there in wordslist..the word is not corrected.

Comment: You are very close to your answer... (congrats) Make the program process the Input _again and again_ until there are no undesired repeated characters.

Comment: Actually i have to run nearly 2000 text files on each domain and process them.If i process the same file again and again the server load and the response time will be increased.Can you elaborate your explanation please?

Comment: You might want to look at a [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) process for determining the correct word.  Soundex is not perfect but might get you closer to correcting most of your misspelled words.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task... I did notice that your code contains

```
    word.toLowerCase();
```

I think you want

```
    word = word.toLowerCase();
```

to normalize *both* text Strings for the comparison.

You could use Pattern/Matcher to make your text changes (compiling the Pattern in the class rather than at runtime), or iterate over each substring character - duplicates are where the character at position x equals the one at x+1 - so you can tell where to remove a character.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to write a recursive fonction that remove one letter and call himself if the world is not in the dictionnary.
It will work fine with your example but not in the real world.

I explain : in french you have the word "terrasse" so my question is how to detect this word if i write "terasse" or "terrrasssse" or "terrrase".

The Martin's answer make me think of THE solution.

For every words in your dictionnary you associate a regular expression that could detect all the letters that are write one or more time.

return to my example:

For "terrasse" you generate (and you stock it - not during the runtime) a regex like this :

[begin][**t**(one or more time)][**e**(one or more time)][**r**(one or more time)][**a**(one or more time)][**s**(one or more time)][**e**(one or more time)][end]

so all you have to do now is to scroll your dictionnary and look if one expression match with the word you want to controll

Perhaps you could accelerate the server time response in controlling only the words in dictionnary that begin with the first letter of the world you have to control.

Hope that it help you...

Comment: my dictionary has 235878 words.You suggest me to write regular expression for all these words?I didn't get you.

Comment: yes absolutely... a piece of code could do that once for all